# входной параметр метода класса?

Tags: python, классы, указатели, методы, инициализация

вопрос: как сделать входной параметр `input` динамическим, а не статическим как сейчас?
(у меня термодатчик будет поливать данными температуры)

написал класс

```
class my_class:
    old_error=0.0        
    def __init__(self,input,output):        
        self.input=input        
        self.output=output
    def my_func(self):
        self.old_error+=self.output
        self.output=self.input*2
        return self.output
        
inp=float(input("inp="))
out=0
class1=my_class(inp,out) # создаю объект класса
while True:
    print("class1.my_func()=",str(class1.my_func()))
    print("class1.old_error=",str(class1.old_error))        
    inp=float(input("inp="))
```

результат работы

```
inp=12
class1.my_func()= 24.0
class1.old_error= 0.0
inp=10
class1.my_func()= 24.0
class1.old_error= 24.0
inp=0
class1.my_func()= 24.0
class1.old_error= 48.0
inp=2
class1.my_func()= 24.0
class1.old_error= 72.0
inp=4
class1.my_func()= 24.0
class1.old_error= 96.0
```

как видно входной параметр не меняется, переменная `old_error` меняется как надо!  переинициализировать объект не хочу, есть метод накопления данных в реальном классе который пишу, какой-нибудь способ нужен, как на Сях например через указатели, но тут их как бы не совсем есть ;)))
в ООП и на python начинающий так сказать, прошу поддержки спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите использовать **глобальную** переменную, то и надо использовать *global*. Как то так:

```
class my_class:
    old_error=0.0
    global inp
    
    def __init__(self, output):
        self.output = output
        
    def my_func(self):
        self.old_error += self.output
        self.output = inp*2
        return self.output
        
inp=float(input("inp="))
out=0
class1=my_class(out) # создаю объект класса

while True:
    print("class1.my_func()=",str(class1.my_func()))
    print("class1.old_error=",str(class1.old_error))
    inp=float(input("inp="))
```

Answer (score 0):

В Python как таковых нет указателей и ссылок на переменные (есть ссылки на значения), поэтому как есть не получится перетянуть такой стиль написания кода в Python.

В вашем случае проще явно менять значение атрибута внутри объекта:

```
inp=float(input("inp="))
out=0
class1=my_class(inp, out) # создаю объект класса
while True:
    print("class1.my_func()=",str(class1.my_func()))
    print("class1.old_error=",str(class1.old_error))
    class1.input = float(input("inp="))
```

В более сложных случаях, например, когда нужно, чтобы у нескольких объектов было какое-то общее состояние/контекст (набор переменных), можно хранить это состояние в отдельном объекте, передать этот объект во все объекты, потом через внешний объект управлять всеми остальными объектами.

Такой объект-контейнер можно с натяжкой считать неким подобием указателя.

```
class my_class:
    old_error=0.0        
    def __init__(self,state,output):        
        self.state=state
        self.output=output
    def my_func(self):
        self.old_error+=self.output
        self.output=self.state.input*2
        return self.output


class State:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input


inp=float(input("inp="))
out=0
state = State(inp)
class1=my_class(state, out) # создаю объект класса
while True:
    print("class1.my_func()=",str(class1.my_func()))
    print("class1.old_error=",str(class1.old_error))
    state.input = float(input("inp="))
```

Также можно использовать глобальные переменные, но это не очень хорошее решение, т.к. жестко привязывает класс к текущему модулю.

Comment: спасибо! очень информативно, действительно хочется отказаться от глобальных переменных, создать доп класс это выход

Comment: @ДмитрийСергеев если ответ помог, можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от него. Не обязательно мой - тот который посчитаете более полезным)